# How to search for similar columns with Python?

Tags: python, pandas

Please, I have two CSV files with columns with company names.
With Python3 and pandas I made a merge to compare the names:

```
compara1 = pd.merge(
    dividas_dep, funrural,
    left_on='Nome_Devedor',
    right_on='Razao_Social')
```

But these files have company names that are not always correctly typed in some of the files. Example:

```
AGROPECUARIA INDIANA LTDA
AGROPECUARIA INDINA LTDA

AGROTRI AGROPECUARIA TRIANGULO LTDA
AGROTRI AGROPECUARI TRIANGULO LTDA
```

So the merge does not find similar values
In Python is it possible to search for high similarity? Note that lines in 'Nome_Devedor' have great similarity in 'Razao_Social'
Is there any tutorial indicated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this library to compare strings:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def similar(a, b):
    threshold = 0.8
    return (SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio() > threshold)
```

this function returns true with string that are similar up to a certain threshold. You can iterate the strings that are not taken in consideration from both files to complete the match.

Comment: Thank you
My Python is 3.6.2

When I try to install this message appears:

Comment: pip install difflib
Collecting difflib
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement difflib (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for difflib

Comment: I think it should be builtin. Did you try without installing ?

Comment: I did so:
def similar(a, b):
    threshold = 0.8
    return (SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio() > threshold)


for i, row in dividas_dep.iterrows():
    a = (row['Nome_Devedor'])
    for i, row in funrural.iterrows():
        b = (row['Razao_Social'])
        similar(a, b)

Comment: Processed for about 5 minutes but did not return anything. Something wrong?

Comment: I can't understand the code from these few lines ! You have the function to find the similarities, you can use it to implement the logic to find the same occurrences.

Comment: In comments you lose the indentation I can't tell you exactly what is wrong.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll ask another question separately